# how to setup capybara-webkit to test ajax calls and get screenshots(html with css and javascript loaded)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ajax, asset-pipeline, capybara-webkit

I'm struggling with capybara-webkit set-up on my little rails 4.2.1 app. Tests are running, links are being clicked on page and ajax calls are working in tests.
Everything seems to work except one weird issue after I started using capybara-screenshot gem. My aim was to get the html screenshots with all assets loaded so the screenshot look like in real life.

So, when getting screenshots, I'm getting two files: 'png' and 'html' file.
When looking at 'html' file (e.g *file:///Users/monk/dev/things/tmp/capybara/screenshot_2015-08-31-16-06-51.840.html*), it had no css loaded. I figured out that asset paths are different from the point of screenshot files location...
OK, so I configured my test environment in 'config/environments/test.rb' file by adding this:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "file://#{::Rails.root}/public"
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

The first line adds the specified prefix for all asset url's on page, the second one compiles the assets and the third one adds that digest hash to asset files. So all the stuff looks more like on production environment.

This makes html screenshots to show up with css and javascript loaded as expected.
But... When I run the same tests, then ajax calls are not being called correctly anymore.. and I get the error

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches [GET] "/things/ajax_calculate_it"
```

So, as soon as I change the default asset_host.asset_host the ajax calls are failing in all tests.

Here's a sample of ajax call on may test page:

```
<a class=" calculable " data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/things/ajax_calculate_it?a=5&b=48">Calculate it</a>
```

Why is this called using GET not POST ? 
There must be something simple to configure. What configuration I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...
Looks like I found the answer by myself.

Simply changed this

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "file://#{::Rails.root}/public"
```

to this

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

After that it seems to work without problems. Ajax called as expected and screenshots are also loaded with css and javascript as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the action_controller asset_host which will change how your pages are generated during tests (and mean that tests are now dependent on the test server and dev server with the potential out of sync issues that can then occur) it's better to set Capybara's asset host

```
Capybara.asset_host = "http://local host:3000"
```

This will cause capybara to add a base tag to any saved html pages and means that only those saved pages depend on the dev server being running and not all your tests.